# Regex to match *RandomName($variable1, $variable2)

Tags: regex

How do I match a string like `*RandomName($variable1, $variable2)`

---

**Some constraints:**

1. The match should begin with `*`
2. The first character after `*` must be one of `0-9, A-Z, a-z, _`
3. The characters allowed in the match are `0-9, A-Z, a-z, _, $`
4. The match should terminate with a `)`
5. The match need not be a single word. i.e spaces are permited within the match
6. There should be at least one `(` and one `)` bracket in the match.

---

**Some Example Strings to be matched**

1. `*RandomName($variable1, $variable2)`
2. `*RandomName()`
3. `*_RandomName($variable1)`
4. `*123RandomName($variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variable4)`

---

Here is what I've got so far
`(^|\s)\*([^;!@#*\[\]{}^|+=:<>"',.~\\&%$-]\S{2,200})\b`

Here is a link to test it: https://regex101.com/r/FxHz7n/1/

Comment: Try `(?:^|\s)\*(\w[\w$]*)\(([^()]*)\)`, see https://regex101.com/r/gukfml/2

Comment: Is the big negative character set really necessary? Looks like you could use `\w` instead

Comment: From your examples it looks like all variable names should begin with `$`. Should that be listed as a constraint?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it worked. Add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @jsheeran I'm checking for that constraint through coding. So that wont be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:^|\s)\*(\w[\w$]*)\(([^()]*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gukfml/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Cs)%5C*(%5Cw%5B%5Cw%24%5D*)%5C((%5B%5E()%5D*)%5C)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - start of string or whitespace  (can be replaced with `(?<!\S)` if lookbehinds are accepted)
- `\*` - `*` char
- `(\w[\w$]*)` - Group 1: a word char and then 0+ word or `$` chars
- `\(` - a `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be:

```
\*[A-z0-9_]+\([A-z0-9_$, ]*\)
```

or if you're doing whole line/exact matching:

```
^\*[A-z0-9_]+\([A-z0-9_$, ]*\)$
```

If you have the following string:

```
*RandomName($variabl)e1, $variable2)
```

The first regex will match the `*RandomName($variabl)` part, the second won't match anything in this case.

Comment: This is a working solution too. I have accepted the other answer since it has been posted first.

Comment: @RahulRavindran Accept answers based on quality and brevity of information, not on who posted it first. The accepted answer concept is used to highlight the "best" given solution to a problem and it is useful for other members stumbling upon the same problem. This is just a general note, I am not telling you to accept my answer.